# Concern regarding a proof from brilliant

Tags: calculus, arc-length

[Here in the proof part](https://tinyurl.com/y5ogaqc7) they deduced that the arc length is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{1+(f'(x_{i}*))^2}\Delta x$$
then said that it was equal to the definite integral. But I didn't understand why. Shouldn't it be $f(x_{i})$ for the limit to be an integral? Since the $x_{i}*$ are not continuous and evenly spaced as $x_i$. Please explain.

Comment: Only when 1+ inside the radical is neglected.

Comment: Please reproduce the proof here, so you aren't forcing users who may be interested to chase links?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please, explain what you're asking, without reference to other sites.

Answer (score 3):

Different authors define Riemann integration in different ways.
In the definition that I think I remember from high school,
to integrate $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$ we define an approximate integral
of $n$ steps by setting $x_k = a + k\frac{b-a}{n}$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, n.$
This divides the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal-sized intervals between
consecutive subscripted $x$ values, $[x_{k-1}, x_k].$
Then the $n$th approximation of the integral is
$$ \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k). \tag1$$
Or perhaps it was
$$ \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_{k-1}). \tag2$$
There actually are distinct names for these sums: $(1)$ is the "right endpoint" sum because you can get it by evaluating $f$ at the right-hand end of each interval
$[x_{k-1}, x_k],$ while $(2)$ is the "left endpoint" sum because you can get it by evaluating $f$ at the left-hand end of each interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k].$

But there are other ways to define the integral. You could evaluate $f$ at an $x$-value midway between the two ends of each interval. That's the "midpoint" sum.
You could average the values of $f$ at the left and right ends of each interval.
That's a "trapezoid" rule.

You could take the "upper" sum, which means you look for the greatest value of $f$ in each interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k].$ This largest value might occur at $x_{k-1}$ (left end), or at $x_k$ (right end), or (in cases where the function has a local maximum in the interval) anywhere between $x_{k-1}$ and $x_k.$

You could take the "lower" sum, which means you look for the least value of $f$ in each interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k].$ Again this might use an $x$-value at the left end, the right end, or somewhere in between.

All of these kinds of sums (except one) are illustrated in an answer to [What does it mean for a function to be Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1581731/139123)
And as it turns out, for functions that satisfy some reasonable criteria, **it really does not matter** which of these definitions we use--in every case we are going to to define the value of the integral as the limit of the sequence of sums produced by letting $n$ increase without bound, and the limit always comes out to the same number.

Now we can do one better: do not even make a rule that says which $x$ to pick within each interval. The only constraint on the $k$th term of the sum is it has to use an $x$ from **somewhere** in the interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k].$
If we say that $\xi_k$ represents a value somewhere in the interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k],$
the $n$th approximate integral looks like this:
$$ \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(\xi_k).$$
Some authors use a different symbol than $\xi_k$.
For example, the symbol might be $x_k^*.$

We can go even further than this, though.
Why does each $x_k$ have to follow the rigid formula $x_k = a + k\frac{b-a}{n}$?
Instead, we merely insist that
$a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_n = b.$
Now the sum looks like this:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - x_{k-1}) f(\xi_k).$$
So now even the $x_k$s are not necessarily uniformly spaced.
This means we cannot rely on the number $\frac{b-a}{n}$ to be the "grid size":
instead, we choose the largest of all interval lengths $x_k - x_{k-1}$
as the "grid size". This also means it is not good enough to say $n$ increases without bound; what we really need is to know that the grid size decreases to zero.
That's the definition shown in [On definition of Riemann integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3449162/139123).

It appears that the definition of integration that was used in that answer on brilliant.com was different from the one you learned.

Answer (score 1):

I would point you to another [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-3/a/definite-integral-as-the-limit-of-a-riemann-sum).
But the confusion arises from the fact that your definition of integral admits only
right-Riemann sum. Whereas, you may pick any point in $\Delta x$ and in the $ limit \rightarrow \infty $, it will work out fine. So you may assume it's $x_i$ and the derivation still works.

Comment: Right.  I would point out that the poster's x_i isn't continuous either, and that the spacing becomes even in the limit, constrained as the number of partitions grows.

Comment: I didn't understand,sorry for being dumb,but could you please explan why that works?

Comment: @AritraBarua Could you be more specific?  Explain why what works?  What part of whose comment/answer are you referring to?

Comment: I'm wondering now whether I overstated the spacing becoming even in the limit.  That isn't needed for the above answer to be correct--all that is needed is to show that the sums converge to the same value, which can be done by squeeze theorem: compare right hand estimation to left hand estimation.  But to prove my point on the spacing might require probability and randomized values, and showing what the standard distribution approaches, and I'm actually not quite sure I have the skills for that.

Comment: @AritraBarua Do you know about mean value theorem ?